# Creating & reading CSV with system own tools

Tags: c#, powershell

There are lot libraries for creating/parsing CSV but how about not using any of them and instead use Windows own tools like PowerShell?

---

I thought I'll try and create some extensions for that purpose so here they are. One for converting a collection into a CSV and the other one for reading a CSV. Do you think it's cheating? ;-)

```
public static class Converter
{
    public static string ToCsv<T>(this IEnumerable<T> objects, char delimiter = ';')
    {
        var currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        try
        {
            using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.AddCommand("ConvertTo-Csv");
                ps.AddParameter("NoTypeInformation");
                ps.AddParameter("Delimiter", delimiter);

                var results = ps.Invoke(objects);
                var errors = ps.Streams.Error.ReadAll();

                if (errors.Any())
                {
                    throw new AggregateException(errors.Select(err => err.Exception));
                }

                return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, results);
            }
        }
        finally { CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = currentCulture; }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> ParseCsv<T>(this string csv, char delimiter = ';') where T : new()
    {
        var currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        try
        {
            using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.AddCommand("ConvertFrom-Csv");
                ps.AddParameter("Delimiter", delimiter);
                ps.AddParameter("InputObject", csv);

                var results = ps.Invoke();
                var errors = ps.Streams.Error.ReadAll();

                if (errors.Any())
                {
                    throw new AggregateException(errors.Select(err => err.Exception));
                }

                var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToLookup(p => p.Name);
                return results.Select(result =>
                {
                    var obj = new T();
                    foreach (var psProperty in result.Properties)
                    {
                        var property = properties[psProperty.Name].Single();
                        property.SetValue(
                            obj,
                            Convert.ChangeType(
                                psProperty.Value,
                                property.PropertyType));
                    }
                    return obj;
                });
            }
        }
        finally { CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = currentCulture; }
    }
}
```

*In order for this to work you'll need the `System.Management.Automation` package.*

---

## Examples:

Test object:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var items = new[]
{
    new Person { FirstName = "Name 1",  LastName ="LName1", Age = 160 },
    new Person { FirstName = "Name 2" }
};

items.ToCsv().Dump();

@"""FirstName"";""LastName"";""Age""
""Name 1""; ""LName1""; ""160""
""Name 2""; ; ""0""".ParseCsv<Person>().Dump();
```

Comment: It's not cheating. It's using built-in tools instead of third-party ones. And it's okay as long as the tool is a) "guaranteed" to be a part of the Windows distribution; b) able to handle various CVS' edge scenarios. Apart from that, I am not sure what your review question is :)

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko I cannot think of any specific question. Just an ordinary review. Perhaps about possible weaknesses, maybe PowerShell conventions etc. Not every question needs to contain a hidden bug. Sometimes it's just a piece of working code ;-)

Comment: `Sometimes it's just a piece of working code ;-)` which is what it looks like to me. Was it a reference to https://www.google.com/search?q=sometimes+cigar+is+just+a+cigar ? :)

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko haha! This is a pure coincidence. I didn't know this quotation.

Comment: That's pretty clever. I wonder though, what advantage does it give you? To use a third party CSV library, you just have to put a DLL in the same folder as the EXE, which isn't very hard.

Comment: @Dangph my idea was that as it's part of PowerShell it should be tested pretty well so I can _blindly_ trust it.